# How escape without using replace function in LIKE with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, escaping, sql-like

Short version: I need a function to escape strings for use in `LIKE` expressions, so `fr_e%d` becomes `fr\_e\%d`.

---

I'm looking for escape the result of a query without the need to use replace.
Because in this result I have path with this char  _  inside. And because I use this result in a LIKE statement, it make the "_" a joker like start *.

I have to use LIKE because I'm doing some stuff concatenation in this same statement who need the fact that I use LIKE.

I tried ~ to replace LIKE but I will have the same problem with the char '.' because ~ is to use regex just skip this solution too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
create function quote_like(text) returns text language sql immutable strict as
  $quote_like$
    select regexp_replace($1, $$[_%\\]$$, $$\\\&$$, 'g');
  $quote_like$;
```

This function prepends all occurrences of `_`, `%` and `\` in provided string with `\`. You can use it for example like this:

```
select * from tablename
  where tablecolumn like
    '%'
    ||
    (select quote_like(substring) from substrings where substring_id=123)
    ||
    '%';
```

Comment: A single pass with `regexp_replace()` - even a clean, simple one like in the example - is regularly more expensive than three instances of `replace()`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: you're right — `replace(replace(replace(...` is somewhat faster than single `regexp_replace`, but not by much — 15-20% in my tests.

Comment: Thanks all for your solutions.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Triggered by @Tometzky's claim:

> Using `regexp_replace` is better than simply `replace` (...)

I have to disagree. Regular expression functions are powerful but comparatively *slow*.
Therefore, event 3x `replace()` is faster than a single, simple `regexp_replace()` - at least in my tests:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quote_like2(text)
  RETURNS text LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
$func$
SELECT replace(replace(replace(
         $1
        ,'\', '\\') -- must come first
        ,'_', '\_')
        ,'%', '\%');
$func$;
```

Note that I use plain single quotes instead of dollar quoting. This requires [`standard_conforming_strings = on`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS-ESCAPE), which is the default since PostgreSQL 9.1.

Try both functions with your data:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT quote_like1(col) from tbl;
```

#### Original answer

Contrary to you question title, you would normally use [`replace()` or a similar string function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html) to prepare your pattern. Consider this demo:

```
SELECT 'abcde' LIKE ('abc_' || '%')  -- TRUE
      ,'abc_e' LIKE ('abc_' || '%')  -- TRUE
      ,'abcde' LIKE (replace('abc_', '_', '\_')  || '%')   -- FALSE
      ,'abc_e' LIKE (replace('abc_', '_', '\_')  || '%');  -- TRUE
```

Comment: You're right too, especially about what solution is faster. Thanks.